# TrackingFunction not working with LocatorPane in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

I want to use TrackingFunction with LocatorPane, but when LocatorPane is used, TrackingFunction does not work.

```
Manipulate[{a, b},
 {a, 0, 1, LocatorPane[
    Dynamic[{a, 0}, (a = #[[1]]) &],
    Graphics[{Dynamic@Rectangle[{0, -.1}, {a, .1}]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-.1, .1}}],
    {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}] &,
  TrackingFunction -> (a = #; b = .9; &)},
 {b, 0, 1, TrackingFunction -> (b = #; a = .1; &)}
 ]
```

Can you please help me identify the problem or provide a solution? I greatly appreciate your assistance!